# Realizar busqueda en un Lapso de Tiempo Laravel

Tags: laravel

necesito realizar una busqueda de un producto en mi tabla pero que sea por un lapso de tiempo. Este es lo que tengo actualmente. Tengo 2 input tipo Date pero no me realiza la busqueda, el campo que utilizo es created_at. Tengo mi tabla ya con datos, ejemplo buscar del dia 2020-08-17 al 2020-08-20, de hecho tendria que agregar un tercer una tercera variable $buscar2 para poder digamos cuanto productos de pelota se vendieron en ese lapso de tiempo

```
   public function index(Request $request)
   {
   if (!$request->ajax()) return redirect('/');

$buscar1 = $request->buscar1;
$criterio1 = $request->criterio1;
$buscar = $request->buscar;
$criterio = $request->criterio;


if ($buscar==''){
    $historial = Historial::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);
}
else{
    $historial = Historial::where($criterio1, 'like', '%'. $buscar1 . '%')
    ->where($criterio, 'like', '%'. $buscar . '%')
    
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(10);
}


listarHistorial (page,buscar1,criterio1,buscar,criterio){
 let me=this;
 var url= this.ruta + '/historial?page=' + page + '&buscar1='+ buscar1 + '&criterio1='+ criterio1 + '&buscar='+ buscar + '&criterio='+ criterio;
        axios.get(url).then(function (response) {
            var respuesta= response.data;
            me.arrayHistorial = respuesta.historial.data;
            me.pagination= respuesta.pagination;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }



  <select class="form-control col-md-6" v-model="criterio1">
 <option value="nombre">Nombre</option>
  </select>                                    
 <input type="date" v-model="buscar1" class="form-control;col-md-3" >

 <select class="form-control col-md-6" v-model="criterio">
                              
  <option value="created_at">Fecha a Buscar</option>

  </select>
                           
<input type="date" v-model="buscar"  class="form-control;col-md-3" >
                            
<button type="submit" @click="listarHistorial(1,buscar1,criterio1,buscar,criterio)" class="btn btn- 
 primary"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Buscar</button>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: tengo 2 input tipo date. desde ahi las realizo. y cada uno tiene un criterio, que en este caso es el campo created_at. Estan en el metodo index de mi controller. Es el codigo que viene al principio

Comment: acabo de subir una imagen de como es que se estan guardando el dato del dia. solo recibo una tipo variable date. Gracias

Comment: ok, subi una imagen del como se realiza la busqueda, se muestra el como se guardo y el como se busca

Comment: Historial::whereDate($criterio1, '>=', $buscar1 )
            ->whereDate($criterio, '<=', $buscar)
            ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
            ->paginate(10);

Comment: lo he intentado asi, pero me da error la consulta

Comment: subi nueva imagen con el error

Comment: ya he encontrada el error, no estaba enviando la variable historial.  Asi ha quedado

Comment: $historial = Historial::whereDate($criterio1, '>=', $buscar1 )
            ->whereDate($criterio, '<=', $buscar)
            ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
            ->paginate(10);

Comment: con eso ya puedo buscar entre un rango de tiempo. Pero si pudiera agregar un tercer criterio,buscar un articulo por el criterio nombre entre esas 2 fechas? como crees que quedaria?

Comment: seria obligatorio, Ejemplo buscar el articulo television entre ese rango

Comment: claro, te lo agradezco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(De lo que te recomendé hacer en la zona de comentarios de tu pregunta), analiza los siguientes puntos que pueden estar causando conflicto en tu resultado esperado:

- De tu frontend mandas 2 variables cuyo tipo `DATE` con una estructura `año-mes-dia`
- Lo tratas de comparar con la columna `created_at` que puede estar incluyendo además un segmento de tiempo [(*recomiendo revises los tipos aquí*)](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#columns)
- Dado lo anterior pueden existir inconsistencias por que tal vez para una comparación de *mayor o igual que* te funcione pero para una comparación de *igual* no te va a retornar nada debido a que los tipos de datos a evaluar no son iguales
- Considerando el punto anterior recomiendo uses [el método whereDate](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#where-clauses) que unicamente tomará en consideración el segmento de fecha ignorando el segmento de tiempo al momento de hacer comparaciones

Entonces puedes construir la query de esta forma:

```
$historial = Historial::whereDate($criterio1, '>=', $buscar1)
                     ->whereDate($criterio, '<=', $buscar) 
                     ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                     ->paginate(10);
```

Si además necesitas agregar otra condición de filtrado que sea obligatoria, puedes después del segundo método `whereDate()` encadenar un método `where` mas así.

```
$historial = Historial::whereDate($criterio1, '>=', $buscar1)
                     ->whereDate($criterio, '<=', $buscar) 
                     ->where('atributo', $variable)
                     ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
                     ->paginate(10);
```

Que a nivel de SQL pudiera lucir así:

```
=> "select * from `historial` 
    where date(`created_at`) <= ? 
    and date(`created_at`) >= ? 
    and `nombre` = ?
    .................."
```

Comment: gracias si ha funcionado, te agredezco la ayuda